# Exclude Records based on values from a different column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that looks like this:

```
| CODE   |  LEVEL1  |  LEVEL2  |  LEVEL3  |   SEC_ID   |
| CODE1  |  LEV1    |  LEV2    |  LEV3    |   123456   |
| CODE2  |  LEV1    |  LEV2    |  LEV3    |   234561   |
| CODE2  |  LEV1    |  LEV2    |  Term    |   345612   |
| CODE3  |  LEV1    |  LEV2    |  LEV3    |   456123   |
```

I need my query to look for the word "Term" in the `Level3` column and then exclude every row that has the same `CODE`.

So in the above example the query would exclude rows 2 and 3 from the result.

Let me know if this is not clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` to exclude any records with the `level3` value and the same `code`:

```
select *
from yourtable t1
where not exists (select *
                  from yourtable t2
                  where level3 = 'Term'
                   and t1.code = t2.code)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e6a8c/3)

Result:

```
|  CODE | LEVEL1 | LEVEL2 | LEVEL3 | SEC_ID |
---------------------------------------------
| CODE1 |   LEV1 |   LEV2 |   LEV3 | 123456 |
| CODE3 |   LEV1 |   LEV2 |   LEV3 | 456123 |
```

Comment: @user1127683 Happy to help, if this answer is helpful, be sure to accept it via the check mark on the left.