# Exclude row based in multiple column value

Tags: sql-server

i need to exclude rows based multiple column conditions like  1) first find value "rev" from column ID1, 2) find the corresponding value in column ID2 based on 1st condition i.e. Ref1, and exclude all the rows contains the value in the 2nd column.

```
    ID1     ID2     VALUE
    post    Ref1    12
    post    Ref1    3
    rev     Ref1    12
    rev     Ref1    3
    post    Ref2    10
    post    Ref2    5

output

    ID1     ID2     VALUE
    post    Ref2    10
    post    Ref2    5
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Tried the query as per below thread, however getting null value. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451035/exclude-records-based-on-values-from-a-different-column but returning null

Comment: If there was a row like <rev, Ref2, 12>, which would be the ID2 value to exclude and why?

Comment: if it is <rev, Ref2, 12> then there must be corresponding <post, Ref2, 12> in the database to exclude both the lines. Basically first two lines the example are posting entries with ref1, then later the posting was reversed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first select all rows having `ID1 = 'post'` then remove all records having `ID1 = 'rev'`, when 'rev' is replaced with 'post'.

```
SELECT * FROM tab WHERE [ID1] = 'post'
EXCEPT
SELECT 'post' AS [ID1], [ID2], [VALUE] FROM tab WHERE [ID1] = 'rev'
```

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/CFiMW9NE).

Comment: Current query working fine...however in case in future if i come across with any other ID1 column value, i want to keep them and only exclude 'rev'. Is it possible to tweak  in the where clause like not equal to 'rev' ( <> 'rev"), similarly in the 2nd select statement instead of 'post', can this be like not to select 'rev'.

Comment: I'm finding it difficult to follow without some examples, can you update your post with a more complex use case that covers this situation too?

Answer (score 1):

This assumes that "rev" stands for reversal or something similar, and that if the ID2 and VALUE are the same for a "post" and a "rev" they negate each other.

I created your table with this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #table1;
CREATE TABLE #Table1 (ID1 VARCHAR(4), ID2 VARCHAR(4), VALUE INT);
INSERT INTO #Table1 (ID1, ID2, VALUE)
VALUES ('post', 'Ref1', 12),
       ('post', 'Ref1', 3),
       ('rev', 'Ref1', 12),
       ('rev', 'Ref1', 3),
       ('post', 'Ref2', 10),
       ('post', 'Ref2', 5);
```

I've then written this query to initially fetch all the 'post' rows of data, then self join matching on `ID2` and `VALUE` and that `ID1` now has to be 'rev', then in the `WHERE` clause adding something to only return rows where there is no `T2.ID1`

```
SELECT T1.ID1,
       T1.ID2,
       T1.VALUE
FROM #Table1 AS T1
     LEFT JOIN #Table1 AS T2 ON T2.ID2 = T1.ID2 AND T2.VALUE = T1.VALUE AND T2.ID1 = 'rev'
WHERE T1.ID1 = 'post' AND T2.ID1 IS NULL;
```